# Exponential Smoothing predicts all null values

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, statsmodels

I have written a program that should forecast the value using exponential smoothing. I have got data for 6 months (from April to September). Based on these 6 months, I want to forecast for the next 6 months (i.e., from October to March).

Here is my code:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from statsmodels.tsa.holtwinters import ExponentialSmoothing

d = {'Month':['April','May','June','July','August','September'],'Value':[2.868,7.205,13.349,20.115,22.769,23.981]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

model = ExponentialSmoothing(df['Value'],trend='mul',seasonal='mul',seasonal_periods = 6).fit()
predict = model.forecast(6)
```

However, when I see the predicted value its all are `Nans`. I am not sure where I'm making the mistake. Could anyone help in rectifying the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the [documentation](https://www.statsmodels.org/stable/generated/statsmodels.tsa.holtwinters.ExponentialSmoothing.html), `seasonal_periods` is the number of periods in a seasonal cycle.

If you look at the equation for Holt-Winters (e.g., [here](https://towardsdatascience.com/holt-winters-exponential-smoothing-d703072c0572)), it includes a term for seasonality which is shifted by `m` steps (where `m` is equal to `seasonal_periods`). This means, that to make a prediction where `seasonal_periods=6`, you need to have the input value in the data `6` timesteps earlier.

Since the data only contains `6` data points there is no way to make any prediction.

Possible solutions:

- Is the data really seasonal with a period of 6? If not, remove the `seasonal_periods` argument or change it.
- Add more data to the dataframe. If you have just one more timestep with data then you will obtain actual predictions.

Answer (score 1):

Increase input datapoints, due to lack of data I guess the model is not able to converge and decide trend and seasonal factors. I added an additional datapoint and the model was able to decide the factors.

> As a rule of thumb, a minimum of two full seasons (or 2L periods) of
> historical data is needed to initialize a set of seasonal factors.

```
>>> data
2020-04-01     2.868
2020-05-01     7.205
2020-06-01    13.349
2020-07-01    20.115
2020-08-01    22.769
2020-09-01    23.981
2020-10-01    22.100
Freq: MS, dtype: float64
>>> model = ExponentialSmoothing(data,trend='mul',seasonal='mul', seasonal_periods=6).fit()
>>> model.forecast(10)
2020-11-01      55.519626
2020-12-01     102.863252
2021-01-01     154.999872
2021-02-01     175.450687
2021-03-01     184.789706
2021-04-01     170.295457
2021-05-01     427.816286
2021-06-01     792.630950
2021-07-01    1194.378883
2021-08-01    1351.966249
Freq: MS, dtype: float64
```

**Reference:**
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_smoothing#Triple_exponential_smoothing_(Holt_Winters)